# Python Local Module Repository (Equivalent of mvn install)

Tags: python

I'm primarily a java developer, and my workflow is to write a library, run `mvn install` to create a package of that library and install it to my local module repo.

Then in other projects in an unrelated directory, i can tell maven to import that file to my project with the maven pom file.  If other members of my team want to use my library, they check out the code, run `mvn install` and then they can import it too.

As I understand, I can use the `import` keyword to import a module into my program, but how do I put that module in a place where python will know to look?

---

In summary: What is the pythonic way to 'install' a module I have locally written?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use [setuptools](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools) for that, since that installs it machine wide (or just locally, as you like), without forcing you to copy things manually.

Comment: would be great that someone could explain how to properly do it using setuptools

Answer (score 2):

In a simple case there is nothing more to it other than putting the folder where your module.py file or your python package folder is located on the PYTHONPATH. The is very much similar how you would put a jar file on the CLASSPATH.

If you want something more complete and standardized, you'd create python package, see https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/distributing.html for details and references. Such a Python package would be an archive file of some format which you could distribute and get installed using tools like *[pip](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/)*.

Comment: Thanks.
All the docs I have found for pip seem to be for downloading things from pypi.  My tools are very specific to my team so I don't want to put them on Pypi.
I guess I'm hoping for a tool that can copy my package into a 'standard location' on the python path.  I'll look into @Jens answer about setuptools.

Comment: You can instruct pip to install from package indexes that are local folders: pip install --no-index -f /path/to/mypackages/